# C# How to get OS to flush IO buffer into file, reading logfile

Tags: c#

I am creating a program to continually read from a log file.

One process is writing to a log file, and the contents are being cached by the OS before written to the disk. If I left click the file in explorer or left click the file in sublime-text the OS IO buffer is flushed and written to the disk.

I have a separate C# process that's reading the file, is there a way to get the OS to flush its IO buffer to disk? I have created file handles to all log files in the directory and periodically call the flush method, but its not working.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.flush?view=net-5.0
"When you call the FileStream.Flush method, the operating system I/O buffer is also flushed."
But this didn't work, I have to manually get the OS to flush the log file by left clicking the file or opening it in a text editor.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
namespace conemu_log_tail
{
   public class FileStreamer
   {
      public FileStream fs_m;

      public FileStreamer( string path )
      {
         fs_m = File.Open( path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite );
      }
   }
   class Program
   {
      public static List<FileStreamer> files_sm = new List<FileStreamer>();
      static bool Flush()
      {
         foreach ( var fs in files_sm )
         {
            fs.fs_m.Flush( true );
         }
         return true;
      }
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
         using ( FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher() )
         {
            watcher.Path = @"C:\Users\ta32\Desktop\ConEmuLogs";

            // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
            // the renaming of files or directories.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            watcher.Filter = "*.log";
            watcher.Changed += FsWatcherOnChanged;
            watcher.Created += FsWatcherOnCreated;

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Wait for the user to quit the program or any key to flush buffer
            Console.WriteLine( "Press 'q' to quit the sample." );
            while ( Flush() && Console.Read() != 'q' ) ;
         }
      }

      private static void FsWatcherOnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
      {
         Console.WriteLine( $"Created File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}" );
         files_sm.Add( new FileStreamer( e.FullPath ) );
      }

      private static void FsWatcherOnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
      {
         Console.WriteLine( $"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}" );
         var fs = File.Open( e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite );
         var sr = new StreamReader( fs, Encoding.UTF8 );
         string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
         Console.WriteLine( content );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [mre]? The `Flush()` method is suppose to do exactly what you state it should do.

Comment: Do you call Flush(true)?

Comment: Its hard to re-produce, you need another application to write a log file that doesn't force flush. I can post the code that i use to read the file. I enabled logging in conemu and i am using the file system watcher to read the logs. 

@CodeCaster yea i didn't call Flush(true) but that also didnt work.

Comment: @gunr2171 with this code, you need to create a new console ( which will create a new log file in your user dir ) then if you press any key flush(true) on the file handle will be called, which i thought should cause the OS IO buffer to be flushed. Its ConEmu thats writing the log file not my application

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to open and read the file via the filesystem watcher, from the FsWatcherOnChanged method as its never called unless the OS decides to flush the IO buffer to disk.

I also cannot use C# the force and external process to continually flush the content to the disk. Having an open file handle to the file and even creating a handle to the file handle and calling flush did not trigger the FsWatcherOnChanged Event.

It looks like I just have to poll the log file.

```
  public string Read()
  {
     var fs = File.Open( Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete );
     fs.Flush( true );
     var sr = new StreamReader( fs, Encoding.UTF8 );
     return sr.ReadToEnd();
  }
```

I wanted to read the content of the log only when its changed. Seems like this is not possible

Comment: The whole point of buffering is to increase system responsiveness and prevent disk wear. Don't do this too often.